# Run time in lua

Tags: algorithm, lua, time-complexity, runtime

So I have the following question which states:

```
function f(n)
    local z=1
    for a=1,n do
        for b=1,z do
            for c=1,z do
                z=z+1
            end
        end
    end
    return z
end
```

and then it gives me the option of:

> Give the best answer to the following.
>
> f(n) = ...
>
> ```
> O(2^(2^n))
>
> O(2^(2^(2^(2^(2^(2^n))))))
>
> O(2^n)
>
> O(2^(2^(2^n)))
>
> O(2^(2^(2^(2^(2^n)))))
>
> none of the others here
>
> O(2^(2^(2^(2^n))))
> ```

This is for my lua computing class and I just have no idea how to do it, I understand that there's a triple loop and most likely instead of `z` they were all `n` it would be `O(n^3)` but for this I'm not too sure.

I was hoping someone could help / explain how to go through such a question.

Thank you.

Comment: When does `z` get evaulated in this statement `for b=1,z do ...`? Maybe it's more simple than we think? Or, try it, and find out that it's very high-order.... ` f(4)` has yet to return...

Comment: The correct answer is "none of the others here".  The time equals to `g(g(..g(1)..)` where `g` is applied `n-1` times and `g(z)=z*2^z`.  It grows faster than any fixed-length power chain `2^2^2...`

Answer (score 0):

**First**, the number of times the `z=z+1` operator executes is equal to the value of `z-1` at the end of the function. So if we could express `f(n)` analytically, then complexity of the `f` function would be `O(f(n))`. Lets try to do this.

**Second**, lets simplify the function. The following loop

```lua
            for c=1,z do
                z=z+1
            end
```

is equivalent to `z=z*2`. Next, the following loop

```lua
        for b=1,z do
            z=z*2
        end
```

is equivalent to `z=z*(2^z)`. Now we can rewrite the whole function equevalently as the following pseudocode:

```lua
function f(n)
    local z=1
    for a=1,n do
        z=z*(2^z)
    end
    return z
end
```

Now we can express `f(n)` recursively:

```
f(n+1) = f(n) * 2^f(n) 
       = 2^(f(1)) * 2^(f(2)) * ... * 2^(f(n))
       = 2^(f(1) + f(2) + ... f(n))
```

**Finally**, lets approximate `f(n)`:

```
f(n)   = 2^(f(1) + f(2) + ... f(n-1))
       ≥ 2^f(n-1)
       ≥ 2^(2^f(n-2))
       ≥ 2^^n
```

where `a^^b = a^a^a^a^a...^a // a is there b times` (which is [Knuth's up-arrow notation for tetration operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)).

I guess that for any constant `c>0` the following inequality is true for huge enough `n`: `2^^n > c * 2^(2^(2^(2^(2^(2^n)))))`, so the correct answer for the question is "none of the others here". But I may be wrong.

You may ask on [Computer Science StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) what is `O(f(n))` for `f(n)=2^(f(1) + f(2) + ... f(n-1))`.